# Why does childNodes return a different value in connectedCallback if type="module" is set?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, es6-modules, custom-element

Calling `this.childNodes` instead a custom element's `connectedCallback` will return a different value depending on whether `type="module"` is set in the script tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script>

    class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        console.log(this.childNodes);
      }
    }
    customElements.define('custom-element', CustomElement);

  </script>
</head>

<custom-element><div></div></custom-element>

</html>
```

In my browser, the following is logged, indicating there are 0 child nodes:

```
NodeList []
```

But if I set `type="module"` in the script tag, there is 1 child node logged:

```
NodeList [ div ]
```

I was able to replicate this behaviour on Firefox 90 and Chrome 92.

Why does setting `type="module"` change the return value of `childNodes`?

Answer (score 0):

Because module forces the script to run after the whole DOM is parsed.

Search for settimeout and connectedcallback here on SO

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer.

`this.childNodes` returns 0 nodes in `connectedCallback` when the script is not a module because the script is executed immediately, whereas when `type="module"` is set the script is executed after the document has been parsed so `this.childNodes` returns 1 node.

### Module scripts

When `type="module"` is set, the script is automatically deferred. In this case, the script will not run until the document has finished loading and has been parsed.

> **defer**
>
> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded.

In this case, the document's [readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) is `interactive`.

### Non-module scripts

For regular non-module scripts, the script is executed immediately so the document is still loading and the element's child nodes are not available.

> Scripts without async , defer or type="module" attributes, as well as inline scripts, are fetched and executed immediately, before the browser continues to parse the page.

Here the document's [readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) is `loading`.

---

###### Sources

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#notes